# Como ordenar porcentajes en grafica de barras

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Hola amigos tengo un problema estoy realizando una grafica de barras en `python` y en un problema me pide mostrar la grafica con su respectivo porcentaje ordenado de mayor a menor. Logre hacerlo sin embargo a la hora de aplicar el `order` no logro colocar correctamente los porcentajes.

```
gen_cnt = pkmn['Generation'].value_counts()
order = gen_cnt.index
npkmn = gen_cnt.values.sum()
sb.countplot(data=pkmn, y='Generation', color=color)
for i in range (len(gen_cnt)):
   cnt = gen_cnt[i+1]
   pcnt = '{:0.1f}%'.format(100*cnt/npkmn)
   plt.text(cnt-20, i, pcnt, va ='center'
```

[image: Este es el resultado sin aplicar el order]

Este es el resultado sin aplicar el `order`. Lo que he investigado es que debo usar tuplas lo he intentado pero no funciona y no termino de entender como aplicarlo. Se agradece muchísimo la ayuda

Comment: Para que pueda intentar ejecutar tu código y modificarlo para obtener la gráfica que buscas ¿podrías poner lo que hay en `gen_cnt`? Si son demasiados datos también puedo apañarme con que imprimas `npkmn` que serán menos.

Comment: `gen_cnt` devuelve 1 166, 5 165, 3 160, 4 121, 2 106, 6 82 y `npkmn` devuelve 800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no tengo acceso a tus datos reales (el dataframe `pkmn`), gracias a la información que me has dado en un comentario puedo crear un dataframe que tenga la misma distribución de valores y contadores, para poder hacer un ejemplo que genere la gráfica que buscas.

Genero así los datos de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

info =[(1, 166), (5, 165), (3, 160), (4, 121), (2, 106), (6, 82)]
data = []
for v, c in info:
  data.extend([v]*c)
pkmn = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Generation"])
```

Aplicando la operación

```
gen_cnt = pkmn['Generation'].value_counts()
```

obtengo el mismo `gen_cnt` que te sale a ti:

```
1    166
5    165
3    160
4    121
2    106
6     82
Name: Generation, dtype: int64
```

El truco ahora es convertir esta serie pandas que tenemos en `gen_cnt` a una lista de tuplas (usando `.items()`) para poder ordenarla con ayuda de una función lambda que tome el segundo elemento de cada tupla (que es el valor del contador). Así:

```
ordered = sorted(gen_cnt.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Ahora `ordered` contiene la misma lista de parejas (valor, contador), pero ordenada de mayor a menor por el valor del contador. A partir de esta lista creo otra que tenga solo la parte `valor`:

```
order = [ valor for valor, contador in ordered ]
```

Y esta es la que le puedes pasar a seaborn para el plot:

```
sb.countplot(data=pkmn, y='Generation', color="#8080f0", order=order)
```

El resultado de la línea anterior saca la gráfica en el orden deseado (observa cómo sin embargo en el eje Y las etiquetas ya no están ordenadas, como debe ser):

[image: Grafica]

Solo queda añadir como texto los porcentajes. Ten cuidado porque al estar ahora las etiquetas en los ejes desordenadas, hay que recorrer los valores de `i` en el orden en que están en la lista `ordered`, para sacar los valores correctos de los contadores y poder calcular los porcentajes. Por ejemplo así:

```
npkmn = gen_cnt.values.sum()
for i, (valor, contador) in enumerate(ordered):
   pcnt = '{:0.1f}%'.format(100*contador/npkmn)
   plt.text(contador-20, i, pcnt, va ='center')
```

Lo que resulta finalmente en la figura:

[image: Resultado final]

## Edición. Otra alternativa

Me he dado cuenta de que se puede ordenar la serie `gen_cnt` usando directamente métodos de pandas (`.sort_values()`), lo que evita tener que crear listas intermedias produciendo un código más compacto y probablemente más fácil de leer:

```
gen_cnt = pkmn['Generation'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
order = gen_cnt.index
sb.countplot(data=pkmn, y='Generation', color="#8080f0", order=order)
```

El etiquetado con texto hay que seguir haciéndolo con cuidado, enumerando los valores en `gen_cnt` en vez de usar sus índices (pues los índices estarían también reordenados y no corresponden al orden en el eje y de la figura). O sea:

```
npkmn = gen_cnt.values.sum()
for i, contador in enumerate(gen_cnt):
   pcnt = '{:0.1f}%'.format(100*contador/npkmn)
   plt.text(contador-20, i, pcnt, va ='center')
```